# disallow taskmanager on windows 10 home

Tags: windows-10

I want to disallow ctrl alt del to access task manager on a windows 10 home computer.
I have tried a lot of technique that works fine on windows 10 pro, but nothing works on windows home.

Did anyone managed to do this on a windows 10 home edition ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could have googled for this but since you ask you can apply a group policy but be warned this will be applied to all the users and will take effect immediately.

Windows 10 Home doesn't have many options that Pro has so you need to add GPedit to your home edition use this [link](http://pureinfotech.com/add-group-policy-editor-gpeditmsc-windows-10-home/) then use that to create a group policy on your computer which will disable the function.

Comment: I have already read this but How can i be sure this link does not contain virus or malware ? Is there a way to download an official gpedit ? Thanks

Comment: Well there's no official way to get the GPedit but links like this you always can scan the file using a virus guard once downloaded. And personally I hardly think that site give out virus infected downloads.